# Bash: Scripts under the same dir

Tags: bash

I have in my $PATH my own path to my scripts. 
I do that adding on my .bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:~/home/user/myownscripts
```

In that directory I have two scripts, but only can use one of them, the first one I did create. And if created another script doesn't work neither.
Only can call the first script created.

The `ls` command return the following output

```
first_script second_script third_script
```

And **first_script** is **bold** and green

**Why? and how fix this problem?**

Comment: Usually the colors associated with `ls` easily helps to find out if a script is executable or not.. this is an easy one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: '~/home/user`? Do you really have a directory tree called `home/user` under your home directory?

Comment: No! That was an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third scripts are not executable. Use `ls -l` (provides more details about the files) to see the permissions of the files and run the following command to make these scripts executable.

```
chmod +x second_script third_script
```

If you run `ls -l` again, you should notice that they now have the `x` bit set in their file permissions.

This is a basic and fundamental aspect to Unix systems and I’d suggest that you read a book or tutorial on shell programming on a Unix-like system.

Comment: I feel like an newbie on Linux and I use Linux atlest about 4 years.  Should delete this question? 
Anyway, Thanks. Your answer was very helpful

Comment: It's up to you. I don't think it would be very useful to other users of Stack Overflow.